# postgresql citus: ctas with select on table with columnar storage runs in error, same select with select on non-columnar storage works

Tags: citus

We run a postgresql 14 with citus_columnar in version 11.1.
Scenario 1: select on 3 tables, where 2 two tables are partitioned and "using columnar". This works     pefectly

Scenario 2: the same select, but with create table as. Here comes an error:
"cannot modify commandid in active snapshot during a parallel operation"

Scenario 3: the same as scenario 2, but the tables weren't defined with "using columnar". This works again.

What leads to the error-message in Scenario 2 ? All 3 scenarios have Plans with parallel-workers.

We didn't expect, that the parallel select in the ctas-statement would run into an error with citus.